# Why is my HTML textbox undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML input textbox, and I'm trying to pass the value of it to a JavaScript function. The code for the textbox is as follows;

```
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="button" onclick="success()">
```

I use this to get the value of the textbox;

```
var depttxt = document.getElementsByID('fname');
```

However when I try to find the value of the value like so;

```
function success() {
    alert(depttxt);
}
```

The alert box says `undefined`. If then put `.value` after the variable in the alert, it breaks and no alert box shows up. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks all!

Comment: learn to use your browser console to look at errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `s` and `D` => `d`. The function name is `getElementById`:

```
var depttxt = document.getElementById('fname');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var depttxt = document.getElementById('fname');
```

Without the `s`.

Comment: Ah, well spotted. It's also a lower case `d` at the end.

Comment: `getElementByID` is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Moan #1: Don't use inline JS :)

Do like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" />
<input type="button" id="buttonId" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = $('#buttonId');
    $(btn).on('click', function() {
        alert('hello world');
    });
});
```

this would be a better way of doing jQuery functions on your site :)

Comment: Upvote for promoting good practice. Double upvote if you show the vanilla method and update jQuery to do the proper value alert

Comment: An user which is having dificulty to use `getElementById()` would understand what you have posted ? Don't overkill the problem. At least explain what you have proposed.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown technically the post was tagged jQuery, so this is valid answer if a little more explanation is added. Not worthy of a downvote IMO.

Comment: @SterlingArcher sure but the original code doesn't approach load events and stuff, user may not know what is it.

Comment: I know, but I'm just happy they are promoting anti-inline-js practices, so I gave points for that alone lol.